# Salesforce silverpop integration

Tags: integration

Is there any document describing how to integrate salesforce with silverpop? I've already checked bunch of websites, but found nothing specific. Thanks for help

Comment: Salesforce has API's which enable integration, and you can build custom soap & rest APIs in apex. It is mostly a matter of what silverpop can do.

Answer (score 3):

In case you’d like more detail on the integration: Silverpop’s digital marketing platform integrates seamlessly with Salesforce.com, eliminating the silos between sales and marketing departments and providing both teams with visibility into each other’s activities.  With the integration, you are able to sync your lead and contact data from Salesforce.com with your Silverpop database, view detailed mailing and Web browsing activities directly within SFDC, enable your sales team to send marketing-approved messages directly from SFDC and easily manage how you would like to sync data between the two platforms. For more information on the Silverpop and Salesforce.com integration, including a demo and customer case studies, please visit http://www.silverpop.com/Partners/Partners-All/Salesforcecom/ or reach out to me directly at fyule@silverpop.com.

Comment: The link in this comment no longer works. Lead to 404.